# What does PUTS PUTS GETS mean in memory access?

Tags: gem5

I recently used the gem5 emulator, which is a system emulator. I have encountered terms such as PUTS PUTS GETS GETX in memory access. What do these terms mean in memory access? Can someone help me? Can you explain it to me in detail?

Comment: From http://people.ee.duke.edu/~sorin/prior-courses/ece152-spring2009/lectures/8.3-multicore.pdf GETX is get exclusive, GETS is get non exclusive, and analogous for PUT.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, this is very helpful to me.